# Clash Royale API message: 'Invalid authorization'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the official API of the game Clash Royale, but it keeps returning error even tho I've done everything right.

```js
data: { reason: 'accessDenied', message: 'Invalid authorization' }
```

My code is right here:

```js
"Authorization": "Bearer MyTokenHere"
```

I've replaced MyTokenHere with my API token, I also added my IP to allowed IPs section. But it still keeps not working with the error above.

I've done all that I've mentioned above.

Comment: You are missing some headers

Comment: I have also tried to the same as you stated in my case its working fine....for which route you are having issue

Comment: I think your IP may got changed.....you can look into https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and then add your Ip and generate new key I hope this works for you